# How to Delete a row in mysql on ExpressJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Trying to Delete a row with express but it's not working.

**CODE**

```
    router.get('/hoteles/Eliminar/:idHotel',(req,res) => {
    var idHotel = req.params.idHotel
    console.log(idHotel);
    var sql = 'DELETE FROM hotel WHERE idHotel = ?;';

    conn.query(sql,[idHotel],(err,result,field) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({
                'code' : 400,
                'faild' : 'error ocurred Eliminar'
            });
        }else{
            console.log('deleted ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows');
            res.redirect('/root/hoteles/1');
        }
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
:5
deleted 0 rows
```

It should be noted that before in others database consults the output is:

```
(node:10899) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.
```

---

The req.params.idHotel  returned

```
:6
```

So I use split() and then I use parseInt()

Thanks.

Comment: answer posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer is below

```
router.get('/hoteles/Eliminar/:idHotel', (req, res) => {
    var idHotel = [];
    idHotel.push(String(req.params.idHotel));
    console.log(idHotel);
    var sql = 'DELETE FROM hotel WHERE idHotel = ?';

    conn.query(sql, idHotel, (err, result, field) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                'code': 400,
                'faild': 'error ocurred Eliminar'
            });
        } else {
            console.log('deleted ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows');
            res.redirect('/root/hoteles/1');
        }
    });
});
```

Don't use semicolon in nodejs. it will defaultly take semicolon(at end of sql statement);

refer more about sql nodejs at [link](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)